# Como recategorizar uma variável "labelled" e atribuir novos rótulos?

Tags: r

Minha pergunta é muito básica e é a seguinte: 
Tenho uma variável "labelled" com dez níveis e diferentes labels e eu gostaria de agregar dois a dois os seus níveis e atribuir novos rótulos a cada um dos níveis. como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse pacote: https://github.com/tidyverse/forcats Para converter de `labelled` para `factor` vc vai precisar da função `as_factor` do pacote `haven`.

Answer (score 2):

Pode não ser o melhor código, mas faz a tarefa:

```
niveis <- data.frame(Antigo = letters[1:10])
a <- data.frame(Niveis = niveis,
              Novo = paste0(rep("NV", 10), rep(1:5,each = 2)))
merge(niveis, a, by = "Antigo", all.x = T)

   Antigo  Novo
        a  NV1
        b  NV1
        c  NV2
        d  NV2
        e  NV3
        f  NV3
        g  NV4
        h  NV4
        i  NV5
        j  NV5
```

O melhor código vai depender se a sua variável está em um data frame ou não